# Open correct reports based off of combobox selections

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm using an Access database in order to store/organize all of the parts for each project. I have 2 comboboxes set up and working correctly: The first is the Customer Name, and once that is selected, the second populates the list of Serial Numbers (project ID numbers) from that Customer. Each project has several components associated with it, in which the reports need to be printed out.

The problem is that most of the component's details are listed in another separate table, so the component number will have to be cross referenced with the table in which it is located and then that report has to be pulled.

This is the table where the comboboxes pull their information from. First the Customer Name, and then the Serial Number associated with that Customer. From there, I want the report from the USER3 table with the associated CATALOG numbers.

[image]

For example, here are my combobox selections:

CustomerName - choosing CIPLA would give me SerialNumbers of either EF-1092,96, or 99

I pick Serial Number EF-1096 next - which has CATALOG numbers EDF50-00170 (in the MV table from USER3),EDF12-01114 (in the FIL table), and EDF12-00532 (isn't assigned a table).

So, for EDF50-00170, ***here's the MV Table*** with all of the information I want out of it (which the MV report automatically includes):
[image]

***And here's the corresponding report:***

[image]

Now is the tricky part where the EDF50-00170, EDF12-01114, and EDF12-00532 reports need to be automatically pulled from the system instead of me having to go find everything manually. This would be the Manual Valve (shown above), Filter, and Misc reports respectively, that have ALL of the Catalog numbers for the category in them.

I already have all of the tables connected to their respective reports, such as this from a previous combobox setup, and I'm assuming this new one will have to be similar:

```
 If partnumberselect.RowSource = "MV" Then
     DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTManualValve", acViewPreview, , "CATALOG = '" & Me.partnumberselect.value & "'"
```

To summarize, I need a group of reports that are associated with a specific Serial Number. Thank you in advance! I'm sorry this is quite the long winded question.

Comment: As this is described right now, it's too confusing to help you right now.. I think there could be a lookup table for User3 / Report Name that would help you a lot - but I really don't know what the problem looks like. Maybe showing (and labelling)  the other tables and related fields would help

Comment: @dbmitch I added some more pictures and tried to describe them as best I could. Hope that helps, thank you again

Comment: When you say `the correct report` do you mean just filter the report appropriately or do you actually have different report objects?

Comment: @SunKnight0 I mean just to filter through all of the possible reports (for all of the components) to choose the EDF#'s report. They are all in different Reports though based on their component type. Does that make sense?

Comment: That means you need two additional tables. One will be a table of all the reports and the second will be a component to report link table. I assume each component needs to be linked to more than one report, if that is not the case then you just need a link field in your components table instead of a separate link table.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Each component is only in ONE table and ONE report, it's just that the collection of components/reports will come from multiple tables. The tables that the components are located in are in the USER3 column. I'm confused about what you mean by `link table`

Comment: If each component is in a separate table/report (so no two components in the same serial number share the same table/report) then you already seem to have what you need. You can open all the relevant reports simultaneously with code similar to what you have in your question. If the possibility exists that you can have two or more components that are from the same table/report, then you cannot do what you want using Preview you can only print (or print to PDF) unless your reports are set up so that by filtering for both/all components that use the same report, you get the result you want.

Comment: All that of course assumes that you know how to iterate through the components of the selected serial number and extract the table/report for each.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Two or more components will definitely be from the same table/report, just not in the example I posed. The only reason I put it in Preview mode was to save on paper if/when the code doesn't work the way I want it to. In the end, they will all just be printed. All the information is in the table above, it's just a matter of linking it to all the components with  a specific serial number that I'm having a problem with. I can extract them individually without a problem.

Comment: I added some sample code for you. See if it makes sense to give you a place to start. You are a bit unclear on the names of the main table and your combo boxes so I added 'placeholder' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ThisDB As DAO.Database
Dim d As DAO.Recordset
Dim q As String

Set ThisDB = CurrentDb
q = "SELECT CATALOG, User3 FROM [mainSourceTableName] WHERE SerialNumber='" & Me.[SerialNumberSelected] & "'"
Set d = ThisDB.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)
d.MoveFirst
Do While Not d.EOF
    Select Case d!User3
        Case "MV"
            Rem Print MV Report for d!CATALOG
        Case "FV"
            Rem Print FV Report for d!CATALOG
        Rem same for other tables/reports
        End Select
    d.MoveNext
  Loop  
d.Close
```

Example for preview with message box:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTManualValve", acViewPreview, , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"
MsgBox "Test"
DoCmD.Close acReport,"RPTManualValve"
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. What do I put in the Rem Print ... section? 
`DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTManualValve" for d!CATALOG`?

Comment: The correct reports open up, but the filter isn't working (it's showing all of the components in the MV table instead of just the ones selected). The database name is "default_cat", the main table is "_MASTER_UPLOAD", and the combobox names are "CustomerSelection" and "SerialNumberSelection" respectively.

Comment: Also, no matter how many ways I try to make it work, it doesn't like that `for`, it's expecting a comparative condition like `for d!CATALOG = Something `. Thank you for all your help thus far. My statement now looks like this: `Case "MV"
         DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTManualValve", acViewPreview, , "CATALOG = '" & d!CATALOG & "'"`. This opens the correct reports with the FIRST catalog number of that type. Now, we just need all of the rest of the reports of that type to show up. Maybe with a counter?

Comment: That is because you are still using `acViewPreview`. If you print they will all print, but you can't open the same report preview more than once. If you want to test you will have to install a PDF printer or other "print to file" solution, or risk wasting some paper! Or right after DoCmd.OpenReport add a message box and a close command so each report will come up and then close when you click ok on the message box, opening the way for the next report to open.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I promise just one more thing that I just remembered. We only want 1 of each catalog report though. So for instance, if EDF50-00159 is used 4 times in 1 project, I only want 1 data sheet for that component to print out, not 4. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Add the keyword `DISTINCT` to your query, like this: `SELECT DISTINCT CATALOG, User3 FROM ...` that will only give you the distinct pairs of CATALOG and User3, you will not get repeats.